# Android Studio AsyncTask result function

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oop

I have an class `SysCall` extends `AsyncTask`

the constructor :

```
public SysCall(Context context,String [] attr,String [] value,String req_page)
```

using when call:

```
String str_result= new SysCall(this,attr,value,"test.php").execute().get();
```

then i start to analyze the string `str_result` , but it's not good to wait for it, it will freeze the UI.

if I have in my activity class a method that I like to do it when it's finish working that can access all class variable, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What I understand form your question, is that you want to call a method in `activity` after `asyncTask` finished the background work:**

**For that, you have to pass the activity to your constructor of asyncTask:**

**Assuming your `activity` is called `MainActivity`(it could be any other name):**

```
class MainActivity extends .........{
......
......
......

//when you start the asyncTask:

new SysCall(this,attr,value,"test.php",this).execute();


//lets say you have a method called, callActivityMethod

public void callActivityMethod(){

 ....................

}



}
```

**In the AsyncTask, pass the `MainActivity` reference:**

```
SysCall extends AsyncTask,,,,,,,,,,,,

...................
private MainActivity activity;


public SysCall(Context context,String [] attr,String [] value,String req_page, MainActivity activity){

...........
this.activity = activity;


}


//call the method from here
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(........) {
//this is called after your task is finished

//call the activity method
activity.callActivityMethod();
}
```

Comment: that's help a lot, but what if i have to call it in different classes, so i should create the same method  name in every class?

Comment: what do you mean different classes?

Comment: or i can also use `Interface`?

Comment: Just create another asynctask in `activity2.java ` and do the same thing as I told you, or you can use interface. But thats out of the scope of the question. If my answer helped then you got a solution.

Comment: Ask a new question for things other than your question, other than that if the answer solved your particular question, accept the answer so others know. GoodLuck.

Comment: that's helped a lot, but what i am trying to do is to make a unique asynctask for all classes,  I will try with interface

Comment: As long as you can pass stuff to the constructor you can use interface.